# Blank screen when navigating in a .NET 1.1 app in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer-10, asp.net-1.1

I have an ASP.NET 1.1 app that does not work in IE10. When I try to navigate anywhere, I get a blank screen. The html of the blank screen looks like this:

```
<asp_smartnav_rdir url="/MyWebFormName.aspx"/>
```

I have seen the fixes for what sounds like a similar issue for .NET 2 through 4, but there is no App_Browsers folder in .NET 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround that I settled on for this issue is to simply disable smart navigation. I wasn't using those features anyway. I'm not sure why it's broken in IE10 and not other browsers, but I can live without it.

I disabled it by setting `smartNavigation="False"` in the `@Page` directive of my aspx pages. It can also be programmatically set in the aspx.cs file by overriding the `OnInit` method and setting `this.SmartNavigation = false`.